# In Python, what is UIF_CMD and how does it work?

Tags: python, github, indexing, testcase

In Python I observed some projects having an index file(in common folder) with all test names and paths indexed correspondingly using UIF_CMD structure. Even in git hub I found some code using this structure. How should I understand this.

Let's suppose there is this project with 5 test cases and we write index file{ or what's so ever it is } as below,

```
UIF_CMD UIF_CMDTAB[]=
{
test1: test name and test file path
test2: -do-
test3: -do-
test4: -do-
test5: -do-
};
```

what is this structure and how to interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I see that [with C, not Python, on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22UIF_CMD%20UIF_CMDTAB%22&type=Code)

It defines a command table, whose structure is ([here for instance](https://github.com/alligatorYE/OLEDChineseSubtitles/blob/a569087f29453b0aaf11d925bc634b740d7d6075/src/common/uif.h)):

```
/*
 * The command table entry data structure
 */
typedef const struct
{
    char *  cmd;                    /* command name user types, ie. GO  */
    int     min_args;               /* min num of args command accepts  */
    int     max_args;               /* max num of args command accepts  */
    int     flags;                  /* command flags (e.g. repeat)      */
    void    (*func)(int, char **);  /* actual function to call          */
    char *  description;            /* brief description of command     */
    char *  syntax;                 /* syntax of command                */
} UIF_CMD;
```

So you would get the same idea in your case: a table of test, with their name, description and path.